# How to define groups for different variables

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning to handle with Python, actually I set my focus on Tkinter. So I've wanted to code an interface with questions and checklists. If you choose one answer you should get points, and if you have one number of points you should get a result. I think it's a kind of test.

For this project I want to group my checklist-objects, for example in group a are variables 1,5 and 8, and Python should print the times i have choose one group.

My problem is, that I don't know how i can define that groups. I've believed that I could write something like "a = var1, var5, var8" but it doesn't work.

Thank you for helping! I hope that my english is understandable. :)
LoveSpock

**Here is my code. If it runs, I chance the variable-names in names making sense, this are test-names. Additionally it's not ready. :)**

```
*from Tkinter import *
import sys
master = Tk()
var = IntVar()
master.geometry('1500x1000') #Abmessung Fenster
master.title('test') #Tittel Fenster
def create_window(): #Definion und Festlegung neues Fenster
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title('result')
    toplevel.geometry('1500x1000')
    toplevel.focus_set()
def var_states(): #Zeigt wie oft angeklickt wurde
    print('%s %s %s %s' % (var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get()))

a#Erzeugung Checkliste----------------------------------------------------------------
Label(master, text='Choose one answer', font=('times', 30)).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text='male', variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text='female', variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text='male1', variable=var3).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
var4 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text='female1', variable=var4).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
a#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a = var1
b = var2
c = var3
d = var4
Button(master, text='solve', command=var_states).grid(row=5, sticky=W, pady=4) #Button fuer 'zeigt wie oft angeklickt wurde'
Button(master, text='forward', command=create_window).grid(row=6, sticky=W, pady=4)#Button neues Fenster
master.mainloop()*
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: SO can help you better if you supply us with what you've tried. What you are asking here is for somebody to write code for you. Show us what you know and what you've tried, describe the problem, and then let us help build your knowledge.

Comment: Do you perhaps want a Radiobutton instead? If you are asking users to select one answer from the list, Radiobutton makes more sense. Then you create a single variable to pass to each `Radiobutton`. Then you specify a different `value` for each `Radiobutton`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. :) It works.

Answer (score 0):

for storing variables within another, there isn't necessarily a clean way to do it.

I would suggest using `eval`, whereby you store the variables you wish to access as strings inside a list, then evaluate the contents of that string. This would look something like:

```
var1 = "dogs"
var2 = "cats"
var3 = "hens"

var_list = ["var1", "var3"]

for variable in var_list:
    print(eval(variable))
```

Prints:

```
dogs
hens
```

Hopefully this helps!

Note that eval should usually be used in scenarios like this, and not in scenarios where you take a user input, as their code could potentially be ran inside your program. Avoiding that however, `eval` should be good here.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your help. I've try to use it but it hasn't run. I think I've done something wrong. I've edit my question, now my code stands in it. Maybe you want to look at it. Thanks!